# Caesar cypher debug: question marks and random char at the end of output text

Tags: c, debugging, cs50, caesar-cipher

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnA2j.png)

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);
char rotate(char c, int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 || only_digits(argv[1]) == false || argc > 2) // check for th correct input
    {
        printf("usage: ./caesasr key \n");
    }
    else
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[1]);
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        int x = strlen(plaintext);
        char cyphertext[x + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            cyphertext[i] = rotate(plaintext[i], key);
        }
        printf("cyphertext: %s\n", cyphertext);
    }
}

//make a function bool only_digits to check for input is a single digit between 0-9

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    if (s[0] > 47 && s[0] < 58 && strlen(s) == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//make a function char rotate(char c, int n) that rotate c by n on the alpahbet
// cout = (cin -65 + n)%26 +65 (uppercase)
// cout = (cin -97 + n)%26 +97 (lowercase)
// cout = cin (other)

char rotate(char c, int n)
{
    if (c > 64 && c < 91)
    {
        c = ((c - 65 + n) % 26 + 65);
    }
    if (c > 96 && c < 123)
    {
        c = ((c - 97 + n) % 26 + 97);
    }
    else
    {
        return c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

[CLI outputs, question marks and chars added randomly to the cyphertext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxSLV.png)

I can't figure out where the question marks and randoms chars come from;
it seems it only works with a 5-letter input;
debug command finds everything works as intended until the last output letter is printed then suddenly random chars are added.

EDIT: changed line 21 to
`char cyphertext[x];`
did not fix the problem

Comment: In C, strings are null terminated... Think about this and look at the code again... AND, arrays declared on the stack (local to any function) are _uninitialised_....

Comment: @Fe2O3 Pretty new to C so I might need a bit more handholding. Also how can I initiate the array if I don't know the size of it untill the user input an array first?

Comment: `memset(cyphertext, 0, sizeof(cyphertext));` Initializing the whole array with zeros isn't really necessary, but it will fix the problem, and `memset` is how you do it when the array size is only known at runtime.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like 64 or 91. C has standard functions `isupper` and `islower`, use those. If you need the code of say the letter Z, it is spelled `'Z'`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks man I initialized the array on top and gave it size 100 seems good enough to brute forced the problem.  I'm sure memset works too will use it in the future.

Comment: Eg: `int func( void ) { int arr[ 23 ] = { 0 }; /* do stuff */ return value; }` In my book beginners shouldn't be using _variable length arrays_ until they've mastered multi-dimensional fixed size arrays and appropriate indexing... Just an opinion...

Comment: You got a couple of good answers.  Please accept the best one by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: To consider for future assignments: @chqrlie has provided a link to the CS50 assignment. Read it carefully. There is no need to _buffer_ the ciphertext before outputting it in its entirety. There was no need to terminate the buffer that shouldn't be there (according to the spec.)

Comment: Line numbers (re your edit) are not very helpful as we would have to paste it into an editor to figure out what you mean.  It's better to use a comment in your c code to indicate a location to refer to an existing line.  We don't want YOU to fix the code in the question only revise it with clarification and to provide whatever data requested.  If you change the question or the code materially then we everyone that answered your question would have to rework their answers which is not great.  Hopefully it's helpful for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output string is not null terminated: you added space for the null byte at the end, but you did not set it explicitly. The array `cyphertext` is uninitialized, so the character at `cyphertext[i]` may be anything and `printf` outputs it, then keeps reading and printing characters present in memory after the array, which is undefined behavior.

You should set the null terminator after the `for` loop with

```
            cyphertext[x] = '\0';
```

Also note these problems:

- for readability, you should use character constants such as `'A'` instead of explicit ASCII codes like `65`.
- `only_digits` should test all characters and accept strings longer than 1 byte for key values up to 25.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);
char rotate(char c, int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || only_digits(argv[1]) == false) // check for th correct input
    {
        printf("usage: ./caesasr key \n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[1]);
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        int x = strlen(plaintext);
        char cyphertext[x + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            cyphertext[i] = rotate(plaintext[i], key);
        }
        cyphertext[x] = '\0';
        printf("cyphertext: %s\n", cyphertext);
        return 0;
    }
}

//make a function bool only_digits to check for input is a string with one or two digits

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len < 1 || len > 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//make a function char rotate(char c, int n) that rotate c by n on the alpahbet
// cout = (cin - 'A' + n) % 26 + 'A' (uppercase)
// cout = (cin - 'a' + n) % 26 + 'a' (lowercase)
// cout = cin (other)

char rotate(char c, int n)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    {
        return (c - 'A' + n) % 26 + 'A';
    }
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    {
        return (c - 'a' + n) % 26 + 'a';
    }
    else
    {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: `only_digits()` is not a good solution. After checking for `argv[1]`, the return from `atoi()` (better `strtol()`) would be enough to disqualify any CLI value not in the range 1 <= x <= 25... Less code is better code... :-) And, `else` after a `return` in the "true" body of an `if()` gives me the willies! Is it our duty to demonstrate _better_ code?

Comment: @Fe2O3: in `rotate`, the `if` / `else` dispatch with 3 `return` statements are not really problematic IMHO and probably more readable than a single `return` with chained conditional operators. The posted code for this function has a more subtle issue: `c` is updated if the first test is true, and the modified value is tested again in the second `if`... this logic error that does not have bad consequences for this particular algorithm but should nevertheless be fixed.

Comment: @Fe2O3: the [assignment](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/2/caesar/) is explicit about checking for a digits only argument.  The key can be in the range 0 - 2^31-1 (which I do not support).

Comment: Dunno... Just read the spec (thanks!) to discover _output each enciphered character after it has been rotated_. This obviates the need for `ciphertext[]` and the absent termination of that buffer, having the effect that the OP's question is moot... Please look again. There's no need for _any_ `else` in this code as written...

Comment: @Fe2O3: of course there is no need for the `else` statements, but I like the 3 `return` statements to be aligned :)

Answer (score 0):

This means the variable `cyphertext` is an array of characters and you need to terminate it with `'\0'` to make it a string.  `printf("%s", ...)` requires a string and if you don't provide one your program exhibits undefined behavior.

The best option is to add the terminator right after your `for`-loop in `main()`:

```
cyphertext[x] = '\0';
```

2nd best option is to initialize the variable:

```
char cyphertext[x + 1];
memset(cyphertext, 0, sizeof cyphertext);
```

3rd (least) best option is to tell `printf()` how many charterers to print.  Many commonly used functions require a string (`strlen()`, `strcmp()`, `strtok()`), and only some also come in a variant that allows you to specify the length (`strnlen()`, `strncmp()`) but there is no `strntok()`:

```
printf("cyphertext: %.*s\n", x, cyphertext);
```

Btw, prefer a better variable name than `x` for the length of your input string.  `n` is a often used convention; `length` or `size` would work, too.